# Variable that shows permanent change in a dicthomous variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I'm trying to create a dummy variable that will illustrate the change of another dummy variable which is dichotomous for my cross-sectional time series panel data.

In other words, I have a variable (going to refer to this as variable named `open`) that contains 3 values: `1 0 NA` .

`open` indicates whether a country goes through a transition to a more openly society, such that, the variable most likely will repeat it self.
I'm trying to code 3 different dummy variables that illustrates changes in `open` such that:

`open1` will have the value of 1 every time there is a positive numerical change in `open` (thus, it will not recognize whenever `open` goes from either `NA` to `1`) but only from `0` to `1`

`open2` will illustrate the opposite of `open1`. That is, whenever `open` goes from `0` to `1`. Similarly, not recognizing differences in regard to `NA`.

`open3` needs obtain the value `1` during a year that `open` goes from `0` to `1` and retains that value for a minimum of 5 years.

I have tried to illustrate the variables by the following data:

```
#    Country Year open open1 open2 open3
# 1       US    1    1     0     0     0
# 2       US    2    0     0     1     0
# 3       US    3    1     1     0     0
# 4       US    4   NA     0     0     0
# 5       US    5    0     0     0     0
# 6       US    6    0     0     0     0
# 7       UK    1   NA     0     0     0
# 8       UK    2    0     0     0     0
# 9       UK    3    1     1     0     1
# 10      UK    4    1     0     0     0
# 11      UK    5    1     0     0     0
# 12      UK    6    1     0     0     0
# 13      UK    7    1     0     0     0
```

### Data

```
read.table(
  text =
    "Country, Year, open, open1, open2, open3
US, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
US, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0
US, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0
US, 4, NA, 0, 0, 0
US, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
US, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0 
UK, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0
UK, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0
UK, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1
UK, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0 
UK, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0
UK, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0
UK, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice description, but where exactly do you have programming problems? Your question does not contain any code at all.

Comment: At this point my previous tries is a serious mess of random coding, I have tried to use the ifelse function but to be honest I have not had much luck finding an approach wherein the dummy variable show change.

Comment: i.e. does not mirror (or give the opposite for that matter) in regard to original open-variable

Comment: Identify your main problem, boil it down to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How do I make a variable depend on change in another variable?
I.e. how do I code the switches of open variable, I guess it should be fairly easy to do the opposite for open2, but I cannot figure out how do I code it so it recongizes the switches of open

Answer (score 1):

The first two requirements are straightforward.

1. Compute the vector `open` differences;
2. If they are positive they went from 0 to 1, if they are negative they went from 1 to 0. `NA`'s are dealt with later.

```r
open1 <- as.integer(c(0L, diff(df1$open)) == 1L)
open1[is.na(open1)] <- 0L
identical(df1$open1, open1)
#> [1] TRUE

open2 <- as.integer(c(0L, diff(df1$open)) == -1L)
open2[is.na(open2)] <- 0L
identical(df1$open2, open2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The 3rd requirement is solved with a run length encoding trick. Get the repeats of 1 of length equal to or greater than 5, substitute those `FALSE/TRUE` for the values and inverse rle.

```r
r <- rle(df1$open)
r$values <- as.integer(r$lengths >= 5 & r$values == 1L)
open3 <- c(0L, diff(inverse.rle(r)))
identical(df1$open3, open3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## By Country

Now write the above as functions and apply each function to the data split by country.
Below is a `by` solution. I test it after ordering as the original (`order` is its own inverse function) comparing the original `df1` with its first 3 columns plus the code's result and the two are identical.

```r
fun1 <- function(x, d = 1L) {
  o <- as.integer(c(0L, diff(x)) == d)
  o[is.na(o)] <- 0L
  o
}

fun2 <- function(x, d = 1L, nyears = 5L) {
  r <- rle(x)
  r$values <- as.integer(r$lengths >= nyears & r$values == d)
  o <- c(0L, diff(inverse.rle(r)))
  o
}

res <- by(df1, df1$Country, FUN = \(X) {
  cbind(
    open1 = fun1(X$open, 1L),
    open2 = fun1(X$open, -1L),
    open3 = fun2(X$open)
  )
})

res <- do.call(rbind, res)
i <- order(df1$Country, df1$Year)
res <- res[order(i), ]

identical(df1, cbind(df1[1:3], res))
#> [1] TRUE

cbind(df1[1:3], res)
#>    Country Year open open1 open2 open3
#> 1       US    1    1     0     0     0
#> 2       US    2    0     0     1     0
#> 3       US    3    1     1     0     0
#> 4       US    4   NA     0     0     0
#> 5       US    5    0     0     0     0
#> 6       US    6    0     0     0     0
#> 7       UK    1   NA     0     0     0
#> 8       UK    2    0     0     0     0
#> 9       UK    3    1     1     0     1
#> 10      UK    4    1     0     0     0
#> 11      UK    5    1     0     0     0
#> 12      UK    6    1     0     0     0
#> 13      UK    7    1     0     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

I repost the data because in my R session `open` was being read as character. To set argument `colClasses` solves the problem.

```r
df1 <- read.table(
  text =
    "Country, Year, open, open1, open2, open3
US, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
US, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0
US, 3, 1, 1, 0, 0
US, 4, NA, 0, 0, 0
US, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
US, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0 
UK, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0
UK, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0
UK, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1
UK, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0 
UK, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0
UK, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0
UK, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0", sep = ",", header = TRUE, 
  colClasses = c("character", rep("integer", 5)))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm will jump straight into it. You have no idea how much you've helped me!

Comment: @Jens Be carefull with the final `do.call`, the method I have used is probably not the best. Give me a moment and I'll revise it.

Comment: I'm trying to deploy the code to the dataset. I'm struggling to interpret it, but the elaboration before adding the functions certainly helps. I can't seem to figure out where to assign the dicthomous variable. In the res <- by(dataset, dataset$country, FUN =... line of code I can assign the both the dataset and identifcation of year, but when assigning the functions I can't seem to properly assign the dicthomous variable. Would it be o <- as.integer(c(0L, diff(dataset$dicthomousvariable)) == d) ?

Comment: @Jens See now, after the edit. The final order of `cbind(df1[1:3], res)` is the same as the original data set. As for assignment, the function `fun1` takes care of doing `o <- as.integer(c(0L, diff(dataset$dicthomousvariable)) == d)` for a generic vector `x`. You pass it in the two calls in `by`. But as `X$dicthomousvariable`, the data set name is *not* used inside the anonymous function of `by`.